# Why does it prints 10 instead of 3? in C Lang

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 3;
    int b[] = {1,2};
    int c = 4;
    b[3] = 10;

    printf("a = %d\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:  **10**

It is an integer output perhaps, it does not carry any garbage value too, but after when i assign the value to the variable **a** as `a = 5` and above value `5`, it just prints the output as it is, tell me what's going on here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is undefined behavior in your code which is

```
b[3] = 10;
```

When you initialized your array you have allocated space only for 2 items.You are trying to access 4th element and that memory is not owned by array so you are getting wierd results. It has happened that the varible `a` is stored in the same location as `b[3]` so that is overwritten

Try to print `sizeof` your array and check how much memory is allocated for the array